# Conditional formatting of subform is not showing on parent form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have applied conditional formatting on a subform (the record which contains a null value will display with red background color). It is working on sub form fine. But I have inserted this subform in the parent form as a grid and this is showing but not applying the conditional formatting.

So my question is how can I refresh conditional formatting on the parent form?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the subform On Current Event.

Something like

```
Private Sub Form_Current()

    If IsNull(Me.fldName) then

        Me.controlname.backcolor=vbRed

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: i am changing the color of cell of subform grid so what should i give control name in your code? Me.controlname.backcolor=vbRed

Comment: try `Me.DatasheetBackColor=vbRed`

Comment: its not working .....i am changing the color of subform cell in main form .....it is changing color on individual subform but on main form it is not working....

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by _"i am changing the color of subform cell in main form"._If you have this code in the oncurrent event of the subform it should work in the subform, Refer to this site for info on subform. [link](http://btabdevelopment.com/easy-way-to-remember-how-to-refer-to-subforms/). Note what they say about subform container. I advice that you make sure that your subform container does not have the same name as your subform to make coding easier. I usually call the container chdXXX and subform frmXXX